# Non-static method cannot be reference from a static context

Tags: java, android, static, sdk, non-static

I realise that this is a duplicate of other previous threads on this issue, However I have read them and I cannot for the life of me work out how to deal with the issue of 'Non-static method 'getItemAtPosition' cannot be referenced from a static context.'

Here is my code:

```
 public class Favourites extends Insulter {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favourites);

    ArrayList<String> favs = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("favs");
    ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, favs);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favsList);
    listView.setAdapter(theAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String copyFav = String.copyValueOf(AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));
            myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("copyFav", copyFav);
            myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.copied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: you need to use `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parent` object of AdapterView which is  first parameter in `onItemClick` method to call `getItemAtPosition` method :

```
String copyFav = String.copyValueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
                                         .toString(). toCharArray());
```

Problem is occurring because `getItemAtPosition` is not `static` method and you to use valid object to call it.

Comment: I changed the code as you said however I get a different error copyValueOf (Char [ ] ) in string cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object). Any ideas?

Comment: @James: see my edit answer

Comment: @James: But why not using just `String copyFav =parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
                                         .toString()` ?

Comment: I'm pretty new to all this, I think it might have been part of a tutorial I was following, Thank you very much for your help.